# How to apply a .pp to a node

Tags: puppet

I'm new to puppet and I can't apply a .pp to change the motd.

I have under **/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/helloworld/manifests**

init.pp

```
class helloworld {
    notify { 'hello, world!': }
}

node 'kp2.keepy-i.com'{
    include helloworld
}
```

motd.pp

```
 class helloworld::motd {
    file { '/etc/motd':
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode    => '0644',
    content => "hello, world!\n",
    }
 }
```

If I execute **puppet agent -t --verbose**

```
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for kp2.keepy-i.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1463497694'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
```

but nothing change.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules` is a base module path. You should not put modules that you invoke by declaration in there. You should put modules that you reference (e.g. stdlib) in there. This module belongs in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/'environment'/modules/`. I recommend reading documentation about directory environments.

More to the point, you are compiling a catalog for the default environment 'production'. The default manifest utilized for that would be at `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp`. Your node definitions belong there. The `include helloworld` in the node definition will invoke the module at `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/environment/modules/helloworld/init.pp` which should have a class name of `helloworld` so it will autoload. If your `init.pp` contains an `include helloworld::motd` or `class { 'helloworld::motd': }`, then that manifest will be invoked from `helloworld` and you will have the desired behavior.